# WPF. Кастомный стиль окна. Добавление стандартной анимации сворачивания и разворачивания

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, xaml, pinvoke

Существует стиль для окна с такими сеттерами:

```
<Setter Property="Window.AllowsTransparency"    Value="True" />
<Setter Property="Window.WindowStyle"           Value="None" />
```

В самом шаблоне определён `Border` со своим `Border.Effect`. Благодаря этому окну можно настроить любую тень включая её размер, цвет, блюр и т.д. НО в чём, собственно, неприятность. Если `Window.WindowStyle == None`, то стандартные анимации Window при сворачивании и разворачивании окна уже не работают. И тут получается безысходность, Вам нужно либо довольствоваться стандартной тенью, либо установить `WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"` и радоваться анимации, но при этом тень у окна будет стандартной. Либо тень, либо анимация.

*А теперь вопрос:*

Допустим я переопределил стиль окна, у меня всё класс всё хорошо, есть кастомная тень красного цвета, но нет анимации.
Каким образом можно добавить окну эти стандартные анимации? (при сворачивании и разворачивании)
Если есть способ в пределах C# и WPF, то прошу поделиться. Если нет, то по-любому должен быть низкоуровневый способ. **WinAPI**, **PInvoke**...

Или же здесь кроется какая-то хитрость, которую я не знаю. Неужели нельзя и тень окну переопределить и при этом анимацию оставить?

Comment: Вопроса наверно 3 видел на русском стаке подобных, да вот ответов я так и не увидел. На англоязычном нашел что то вроде такого https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418160/custom-window-style-with-minimize-animation

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, я что-то сразу не догадался поискать сначала на англоязычном. Попробую данное решение

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну, в общем-то попробовал. Всё бы хорошо, но не работает :D Да и в моём случае нужно, что бы было AllowsTransparency="True". Последний ответ в этой теме более-менее подходящий под мой вопрос, но.. мне нужно, чтобы было одно окно, а не два, где второе имитирует анимацию. Ибо выглядит это крайне странно...

Есть ещё варианты у кого-нибудь?

Comment: А для чего вам `AllowsTransparency`? Я лично его использовал для тени и тоже с этим столкнулся. Вот сейчас нашел [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372303/dropshadow-for-wpf-borderless-window) способ эффекта тени. Если у вас тоже для тени используется данный параметр, то попробуйте выставить в `False` и попробовать способ по ссылке.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, для тени. Для чего же ещё. Просто хочется кастомную тень и при этом не терять анимацию.
Спасибо, попробую